# PHP file database upload

Tags: php

don't have much experience with php programming and web in general, so I've build this code from tutorials and what it supposed to do is to store data in database, but it seems like it completely ignores any statement(e.g. exception when choosing incorrect data format) and it sort of just refreshes the page after hiting submit button, any ideas how to fix this?

```
<div id='box'>
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['video'])){

        $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $type = explode('.', $name);
        $type = end($type);
        $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
        $randon_name = rand();
        $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];

     if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4' && $type != 'flv' && $type !='avi'){
            $message = "bad format";

        }   
           else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES('', '$name', 'videos/$randon_name.$type')");
            $message = "successful upload";
        }
        echo $message;
    }
    ?>
    Choose file : <br/>
    <input type='file' name='video'/>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'/>

    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: i think it is nt proper isset($_FILES['video'] do it as isset($_FILES['video']['name'])

Comment: @M.chaudhry `isset()` is a function. Parenthesis are required.

Comment: @RUJordan sry edited :)

Comment: `$_FILES['video']['name']` comes from the client, thus your query is open to injection.  Look into PDO.

Comment: What do you see if you add `print_r($_FILES);` at the very top of your PHP script?

Comment: Zenia with your if condition try to echo  $name  and tell does it working ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the case that you selected a file larger than your upload_max_filesize or post_max_size.
If this is the case then the `$_FILES` variable is empty and you see nothing. If you select a smaller file you should see something when doing a `print_r($_FILES)` at the top of your script.

if you run php in apache as a module you can try to add a .htaccess like this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
```

Otherwise you need to edit your php.ini. As far as i know you cannot set these php.ini values via `ini_set()`.

Comment: i copied your code and added a `print_r($_FILES);` at the top of the script. When I upload a jpeg with around 1MB, i can see the "bad format" output and the file details printed by my `print_r`. If I choose a .wmv video with 25MB, the `print_r` shows an empty array. The `if(isset($_FILES['video']))` fails and i can see nothing else. After adding the .htaccess file, the 25MB .wmv works like the 1MB .jpg.

Comment: <?php
print_r($_FILES);
if($_FILES['video']['name']){
is this it where it needs to be added?

Comment: because if that's how you do it, then i don't see what you see